# Need some direction sale date "rest" query

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build a query that will tell me which items need to "rest" from being on sale. Each item has an item number and a two letter prefix. (IE: 1234567 DT) if I have item 1234567 DT on sale until 3/11/2018 and that item 1234567 in prefix DU is being mailed out before the "rest" period of 30 days, lets say it mails on 4/4/2018 I would want it to show up in the query.

Since the End dates and mail dates are by Prefix and not item number I've created a table that has all the prefixes and their sale end dates and mail dates.

What I'm trying to do now is figure out the best way to build a query that uses the date table (PDTT) and looks at the end date vs the mail date and picks out anything that conflicts with the 30 day rest period.

I've created a query for each prefix that includes the end date and mail date table I created and from that I created a secondary query that uses the prefix queries and I started testing the following but i'm not getting the right results.

```
SELECT 
  [1 EB Date Tests DT].Pack, 
  [1 EB Date Tests DT].[EB End Date], 
  [1 EB Date Tests DU].[Mail Date], 
  DateAdd("d",-30,[1 EB Date Tests DU]![Mail Date]) AS Conflicts
FROM ([1 EB Date Tests DT] 
INNER JOIN [1 EB Date Tests DU] ON 
  ([1 EB Date Tests DT].Owner = [1 EB Date Tests DU].Owner) AND ([1 EB Date Tests DT].Pack = [1 EB Date Tests DU].Pack)) 
INNER JOIN 1PDTT ON 
  ([1 EB Date Tests DU].Prefix = [1PDTT].Prefix) AND ([1 EB Date Tests DT].Prefix = [1PDTT].Prefix)
ORDER BY [1 EB Date Tests DT].Pack;
```

The PDTT table shows as follows:

```
ID  Prefix  Mail Date   EB End Date WS End Date
2   DT  12/14/2018  3/11/2019   1/30/2019
3   DF  12/27/2018  3/11/2019   2/27/2019
4   DU  3/30/2019   3/11/2019   2/27/2019
5   DB  2/22/2019   6/17/2019   
6   DA  3/1/2019    6/17/2019   
7   DM  4/19/2019   6/17/2019
```

Each of the prefixes has a query that shows the pack number and prefix and is joined to the prefix of this table.

I'm not even sure this is the right direction to go. Any thoughts, ideas or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Show whole SQL-Code and tables structure. You check for equatity, but don't you need less than too?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need to know what's within the 30 day rest period so 30 days or less, any conflicts need to show up. Also I've edited to show what I have in the table and the SQL code.